# How to get the SUM of one column based on another?

Tags: sql, sum

My current SQL Query:

```
SELECT WorkOrderParts.PartQTY,
       '$' + CONVERT(varchar(22), WorkOrderParts.PartCost, 1) AS PartCost,
       '$' + CONVERT(varchar(22), WorkOrderParts.PartQTY * WorkOrderParts.PartCost, 1) AS PartsTotal,
       tblParts.fldMfgPartNumber
FROM  tblWorkorders
INNER JOIN WorkOrderParts ON tblWorkorders.ID = WorkOrderParts.WorkOrderId
INNER JOIN tblParts ON WorkOrderParts.PartId = tblParts.ID
WHERE (tblWorkorders.ProcessedDate BETWEEN '5/1/2012 12:00:00 AM'
                                       AND '5/2/2012 12:00:00 AM')
GROUP BY tblWorkorders.ProcessedDate, WorkOrderParts.PartCost,
         WorkOrderParts.PartQTY, tblParts.fldMfgPartNumber, tblWorkorders.ID
ORDER BY tblParts.fldMfgPartNumber
```

**The data being returned:**

```
PartQTY  PartCost  PartsTotal  fldMfgPartNumber 
-------  --------  ----------  ----------------
1        $48.71    $48.71      1878042C91
1        $48.71    $48.71      1878042C91
1        $48.71    $48.71      1878042C91
1        $11.82    $11.82      1R1804
1        $11.82    $11.82      1R1804
1        $11.82    $11.82      1R1804
4        $255.39   $1,021.56   2697041
1        $8.94     $8.94       3719
```

**How can I modify my SQL Query to return the following results:**

```
PartQTY  PartCost  PartsTotal  fldMfgPartNumber 
-------  --------  ----------  ----------------
3        $48.71    $146.13     1878042C91
3        $11.82    $35.46      1R1804
4        $255.39   $1,021.56   2697041
1        $8.94     $8.94       3719
```

Comment: You need to take tblWorkorders.ProcessedDate out of the group by, I think.  Those are probably unique.  Removing that will group you results properly (I think)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like the [`GROUP BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) statement?

`select sum(PartQTY), avg(PartCost), sum(PartsTotal), fldMfgPartNumber from Table group by fldMfgPartNumber`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that tblParts.fldMfgPartNumber is the column you'd like to group by (which I guess is - basing on your expected resultset), then you can try something like:

```
    SELECT SUM(WorkOrderParts.PartQTY), 
   '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(22), MIN(WorkOrderParts.PartCost), 1) AS PartCost, 
   '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(22), SUM(WorkOrderParts.PartQTY * WorkOrderParts.PartCost), 1) AS PartsTotal, 
    tblParts.fldMfgPartNumber 
 FROM tblWorkorders 
 INNER JOIN WorkOrderParts ON tblWorkorders.ID = WorkOrderParts.WorkOrderId 
 INNER JOIN tblParts ON WorkOrderParts.PartId = tblParts.ID 
 WHERE (tblWorkorders.ProcessedDate BETWEEN '5/1/2012 12:00:00 AM' AND '5/2/2012 12:00:00 AM') 
 GROUP BY tblParts.fldMfgPartNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(WorkOrderParts.PartQTY) as PartQTY, '$' + CONVERT(varchar(22),
       WorkOrderParts.PartCost, 1) AS PartCost, '$' + CONVERT(varchar(22), 
       WorkOrderParts.PartQTY * WorkOrderParts.PartCost, 1) AS PartsTotal,
       tblParts.fldMfgPartNumber
FROM  tblWorkorders
INNER JOIN WorkOrderParts ON tblWorkorders.ID = WorkOrderParts.WorkOrderId
INNER JOIN tblParts ON WorkOrderParts.PartId = tblParts.ID
WHERE (tblWorkorders.ProcessedDate BETWEEN '5/1/2012 12:00:00 AM'
                                       AND '5/2/2012 12:00:00 AM')
GROUP BY tblWorkorders.ProcessedDate, WorkOrderParts.PartCost,
         tblParts.fldMfgPartNumber, tblWorkorders.ID
ORDER BY tblParts.fldMfgPartNumber
```